# How find the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

I want find a closed Form for below integral$$\int \frac{1}{-1-aX+\frac{1}{2}bX^2} dX$$.

thanks for help

Comment: The closed form will depend on some details of the values of $a$ and $b$. As a simple illustration, if $b=-2$ and $a=0$ we get an arctan. And often we get combination of logs stuff. And then there are a few weird cases, like $b=0$, or double root cases. Are there useful restrictions on the coefficients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Complete the square first $$\frac{b}{2}X^2-a X-1=\frac{b}{2}\Big(X^2-\frac{2a}{b}X-\frac{2}{b}\Big)=\frac{b}{2}\Big((X-\frac ab)^2-(\frac {a^2}{b^2}+\frac 2b)\Big)$$ In the most general case, the change of variable becomes clear.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $b=0$, then (moved and scaled) logaritm, if $a^2+2b<0$, then (moved and scaled) arctan, if $a^2+2b=0$, then (moved and scaled) $1/x$, if $a^2+2b>0$, then sum of two (moved and scaled) logarithms.